# Viewpager doesn't update/loads xml items

Tags: android, android-viewpager, instant

I solved the question with onclicklistsner issue with viewpager but now I noticed, that it depends on all Elements in XML Layout files.

I implemented a ViewPager with that Tutorial: [tutsplus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)

Now I have the Problem, that all the Objects I defined in XML are instantiated correct (not null in Debuggin mode after findViewById etc) but I can't reffer to them. 
To understand it better here my PagerAdapter:

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.settings_view;

            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.push_view;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.listen_view;
            break;

        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;


    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }


}
```

and here my implementation of the adapter and a bit of sample code:

```
 ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
       myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
       myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Spinner spinner = (Spinner)listenView.findViewById(R.id.Dashboard_chooser);
    Button push = (Button)pushview.findViewById(R.id.pushbutton);

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, si);


            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);



push.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {

//do something
});
```

neither the Button nor the Spinner are doing anything. They are both instantiated correct, but I cannot click the buton nor gets the Spinner filled with the Array of SpinnerItems.

In Debu Mode I looked up, that both of them get instantiated, the SpinnerItemArray (si) gets it's values and so on.

By the way, all the things worked before I implemented the ViewPager,and the buttons are also working when setting an android:onClick in XML and then  defining the method in code but that won't work for the Spinner , so I think it must be something wrong with either the instantiateItem Method or something similar.

Does anyone here knows the Problem?
Would be too cool if somebody could help.
Yours Flo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved it withthat link

http://code.google.com/p/ratebeerforandroid/source/browse/RateBeerForAndroid/src/com/ratebeer/android/gui/fragments/SearchFragment.java#486